# Cognitive Search Indexer including all files regardless of inclusion list

Tags: azure, search, indexer

I have a Cognitive Search index that is set to only include PDF files from Blob storage.  However, it is also retrieving other files from storage.

```
Indexer JSON:
      "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".pdf",
      "excludedFileNameExtensions": ".csv",
      "allowSkillsetToReadFileData": true
```

Search explorer query returning JSON file.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://.../indexes()/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 7.668355,
            "content": "...\n\n",
            "metadata_storage_name": "manifest.json",
            "metadata_storage_path":
```

There are some errors in the indexer related to file size but no errors that seem related to this issue.

Also, I have a list of files created in Blob storage by some process in Azure and I cannot determine what the process is. There are folders for each day of the month with DefaultRule-AllBlobs.csv and manifest.json files.  Any ideas where these are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

These files are generated by the [Azure Storage blob inventory feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-inventory).